# Huffman: Can't decompress characters like 'æ', 'ø', 'å' and '•'

Tags: java, arrays, huffman-code

I'm working on my Huffman compression (or decompression rather at this point), and I can't get characters like 'æ', 'ø', 'å' and '•' to be decompressed correctly. The character 'æ' is decompressed to two symbols 'ￃﾦ'. Any idea of what should be doing?

**EDIT:** I think it might have to do with the BufferedWriter and the InputStream (and the others). I probably need to read and write in UTF-8 or something? How do I do that?

**EDIT 2:**: With the help of some helplines I've found that 'ￃ' and 'ﾦ' is written as individual characters to the file. Is 'ø' greater that 1 byte, and maybe I've assumed that every character is 1 byte somewhere?

```
public static void decompressFile() throws IOException {

    
    byte[] compressedBytes = //somecode
    int[] frequencyTable = //somecode

    HuffmanNode root = //some code

    //Generating code table
    String[] codeTable = new String[256];
    Huffman.getCodeTable(codeTable, root, "");

    DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("[//thecompressedfile]"
    BitInputStream bitInputStream = new BitInputStream(inputStream, compressedBytes.length);

    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFileName));


    HuffmanNode node = root;
    int bit;


    while ((bit = bitInputStream.readBit()) != -1) {
        //int bit = bitInputStream.readBit();
        System.out.print(bit + "");

        if (bit == 0) {
            node = node.getLeft();
            if (node.isLeaf()) {
                bufferedWriter.write(node.getAByte());
                node = root;
            }
        } else if (bit == 1) {
            node = node.getRight();
            if (node.isLeaf()) {
                bufferedWriter.write(node.getAByte());
                node = root;
            }
        }
    }

    bufferedWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: Well you need to show us your code if you are expecting any help here.

Comment: I'm sorry. Wanted to avoid it because it's school work, but I realize that I'll have to for you to be able to help. I'm on it!

Comment: Hey! I've added code. Can I have it reopened?

Comment: You need to use a `java.io.OutputStream` (`FileOutputStream`/`BufferedOutputStream`) since you are outputting bytes at a time, not characters at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your read using an `InputStream` and write using a `Writer`. The first one is for reading binary data the second one is for writing text. You are doing an implicit conversion when you call `bufferedWriter.write(node.getAByte())`.

In other words, you're interpreting the binary data as ISO-8859-1, because you're basically casting a byte to a `char` (technically an `int` for ... weird reasons). Then you're writing it back with whatever the platform default encoding is.

This will mess up your text, unless it *happens to be* ISO-8859-1 encoded and the platform default encoding is the same.

A better approach would be to simply treat it as binary data throughout (it's fine if it's really text, as long as you don't care about *interpreting* the text in your code, which you don't seem to do). Since Huffman coding acts on byte streams, that also more closely matches what you're doing with the data.

To do so replace the `Writer` with an `OutputStream` (i.e. a `FileOutputStream`, possibly wrapped in a `BufferedOutputStream` for performance reasons).

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes so much sense, and now it can read 'æ' etc. I changed BufferedWriter to FileOutputStream.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with this line ```BitInputStream bitInputStream = new BitInputStream(inputStream, compressedBytes.length);```. Because it does not include every bit. What should the size of the BitInputStream be?

Comment: I don't know what `BitInputStream` you are talking about, as that's not part of the JDK itself and the Apache Commons one takes an enum as the second parameter and not an `int`. You'll have to check the documentation and/or source of whatever `BitInputStream` you're using.